# Does 'arguments' keyword refer to outermost or innermost function arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Suppose I have following:

```
function a() {
  return () => {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
}
```

What does `arguments` keyword refer to? To arguments of the outermost or innermost function?

Comment: whatever the closest function it is called from.

Comment: All you had to do is try it.

Comment: The quickest way to find out is to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/jfc09bud/
Surprisingly (to me at least) the code writes the outer arguments. I'm guessing it has to do with the way JavaScript captures variables in arrow functions. If you were to return a function instead you get the arguments of that function (the inner function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not have [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Any `arguments` is from the last outer classic function.

```js
function a() {
  return () => {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
}

a('foo')('bar'); // array like object with 'foo'
```